# Wait for Form Submit before API call AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Solution**: No need to look for the PHP variables, just prevent default submission and use the Javascript variable in the API call..

I am attempting to use this workaround to wait for form submission before executing API call. However, the first ajax push is not resulting in the $_POST variable receiving the data. Network analysis shows that the variable is being sent. First question on here, so apologies in advance.

```
   $("#form").submit(function(evt) { 

       evt.preventDefault(); 
       var inputAddress = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();

       // Ajax form Submit
       $.ajax ({
           url:'index.php',
           method: 'POST',
           data:{inputAddress:inputAddress},
           success: function() {

                var add = '<?php echo ($_POST['inputAddress'])?>'; // BLANK?


                    // API call
               var apiResult = $.ajax ({
                   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+add+'&key=AIzaSyDcNLmq6E6K-bDefI-28E1qiqugS_-wnhI',
                   method: 'get',
                   success: function(data) {
                       window.console.log(data); 
                           }
                  }) 
           }
        })
      }) 
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like already have that variable on javascript, so there's no need to get it from $_POST. Try using this way and see if it works:

```
   $("#form").submit(function(evt) { 

       evt.preventDefault(); 
       var inputAddress = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();

       // Ajax form Submit
       $.ajax ({
           url:'index.php',
           method: 'POST',
           data:{inputAddress:inputAddress},
           success: function() {

                    // API call
               var apiResult = $.ajax ({
                   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+inputAddress+'&key=AIzaSyDcNLmq6E6K-bDefI-28E1qiqugS_-wnhI',
                   method: 'get',
                   success: function(data) {
                       window.console.log(data); 
                           }
                  }) 
           }
        })
      }) 
   })
```

EDIT:
Also the first request is unnecessary, so you can remove it:

```
   $("#form").submit(function(evt) { 

       evt.preventDefault(); 
       var inputAddress = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();

       // API call
       var apiResult = $.ajax ({
              url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+inputAddress+'&key=AIzaSyDcNLmq6E6K-bDefI-28E1qiqugS_-wnhI',
              method: 'get',
              success: function(data) {
                  window.console.log(data); 
              }
       }) 
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem in your code. The page containing the above code is a **PHP script**, I think.

So, the Apache(PHP server) processes `<?php echo ($_POST['inputAddress'])?>` and prints ***Empty value into it***.

```js
$("#form").submit(function(evt) { 

       evt.preventDefault(); 
       var inputAddress = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();

       // Ajax form Submit
       $.ajax ({
           url:'index.php',
           method: 'POST',
           data:{inputAddress:inputAddress},
           success: function() {

                var add = ''; // PHP leaves it Empty...


                    // API call
               var apiResult = $.ajax ({
                   url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+add+'&key=AIzaSyDcNLmq6E6K-bDefI-28E1qiqugS_-wnhI',
                   method: 'get',
                   success: function(data) {
                       window.console.log(data); 
                           }
                  }) 
           }
        })
      }) 
   })
```